# Can't understand yield

Tags: ruby, yield

In some project i met this code:

```
erb = yield.src
```

I can't understand what the `src` method is doing and how it's possible to chain to `yield` method.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating your own method that `yield`s on a trivial block, and seeing what the result is?

Comment: I know that yield returns result of the block but this time i was confused by ruby magic

Comment: Don't be afraid to try something, even if you're not sure it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand yield would return an object which has the instance method src defined on it

something like this

```
def foo
  p yield.class
end

foo do 
 1
end
```

This will print Fixnum